# variables javascript a php

Tags: javascript, php, variables

como siempre solicito de su ayuda para poder resolver un problema que tengo entre PHP y Java Script, se que uno se ejecuta del lado del servidor y otro de lado del cliente, el problema es que no puedo pasar variables de javascript a php por ello uso un archivo intermediario, la cosa es, tengo un script que recopila coordenadas del dispositivo, el archivo gen_cord.php es:

```
<html lang="sp"> 
<head>
<script>
var watchId;
var PositionOptions = {
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 60000,
    enableHighAccurace: true
};

function initiate_geolocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    var watchId = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, PositionOptions);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Lo sentimos pero el API de Geolocalización de HTM5 no está disponible para su navegador";
  }
}

function successCallback(pos) {  
  var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
  latitude.innerHTML = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
  var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
  longitude.innerHTML = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);  
    var accuracy = document.getElementById('rangoerror');
  accuracy.innerHTML = pos.coords.accuracy;
};

/* Posibles errores que se pueden producir en la geolocalización */
function errorCallback(error) {
  var appErrMessage = null;
  if (error.core == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    appErrMessage = "El usuario no ha concedido los privilegios de geolocalización"
  } else if (error.core == error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) {
    appErrMessage = "Posicion no disponible"
  } else if (error.core == error.TIMEOUT) {
    appErrMessage = "Demasiado tiempo intentando obtener la localización del usuario."
  } else if (error.core == error.UNKNOWN) {
    appErrMessage = "Error desconocido"
  } else {
    appErrMessage = "Error insesperado"
  }
  document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = appErrMessage
};
</script>
</head>
<?php    
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>\n";
    //obten coordenadas
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>initiate_geolocation();</script>";
echo 'Latitud: <span id="latitude"></span> Longitud: <span id="longitude"></span>';
echo '<script language="JavaScript">window.location.href = "notifica.php?w1=" + lat + "&w2=" + longitude;</script>';
?>
```

el archivo notifica.php es:

```
<?php    
            
            
            $lat=$_GET['w1'];
            $lon=$_GET['w2'];           
            Echo ”$lat,$lon";
            
?>
```

el problema es que el resultado es:

[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement]

Como puedo convertir los objetos a variables y así poderlas pasar a php

Por su siempre atenta y pronta ayuda gracias

Comment: No veo que predefinas `lat` antes de llegar aquí:  `+ lat +`

Comment: Por otra parte, `latitude` lo has definido como un elemento, de ahí tu resultado. Si quieres su contenido usa `latitude.innerHTML` por ejemplo.

Comment: Estimado masterguru, agradezco mucho tu respuesta y comentario, te ofrezco una disculpa ya que no programo mucho en javascript, en respuesta a tu comentario tienes razon no habia definido lat,pero al definirla agregando esta linea: "echo "<script language='JavaScript'>var lat=latitude.innerHTML;</script>"; ya no me manda el error pero me pone la variable vacia, es decir el resultado es:   , [object HTMLSpanElement], quiero deducir que ya le asigno valor a lat, pero no lo toma del elemento latitude, podrias yaudarme a saber que estoy haciendo mal... gracias por tus comentarios y ayuda, saludos

Comment: Siguiendo tu comentario masterguru, coloque despues del script, esta linea: <script>var lat=latitude.innerHTML;</script> y obtuve como resultado: undefined,[object HTMLSpanElement] , quiero suponer que ahora no sabe como es que esta definida lat, gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: No entiendo por qué mezclas tanto el código. ¿El propósito de esto es mandar las coordenadas al servidor mediante un formulario? Si es eso, ¿por qué no creas la latitud y la longitud como elementos del formulario, le asignas los valores y listo? Así, cuando envíes el form, se enviará con los valores que haya en esos elementos.

Comment: Estimado A. Cedano, agradezco tu respuesta, precisamente es lo que no se como se hace en javascript, crearlos como un elemento de un formulario, alguna guia u orientacion?, gracias por tus respuestas